# Piping an alias hangs xonsh

Tags: python, shell, pipe, xonsh

I have the following alias:

```
aliases['test'] = 'grep @($args) somefile'
```

It works perfectly fine, however when I try piping it to anything, e.g.:

```
$ test smth | head
```

it still prints out the full output of `test smth` ignoring the `head` command, and then hangs (and I can't get out of the hung state with Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z and have to kill the session).

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It's working on xonsh 0.11.0

```
~ $ aliases['test'] = 'grep @($args) .bash_history'
~ $ test ls | head
ls -lnrt
ls -lnrt
lsb_release -a
lspci
lspci | grep VGA
lspci
ls -l
vim 
vim
ls -l
```